# Java JTextArea hightliting text with a bold font

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I need several words to be highlighted in a String while appending it to a JTextArea. So that I try this:

```
jta.append("<html> <b>Termination time : </b></html>" + 
                        CriterionFunction.estimateIndividual_top(individual) + "\n");
```

Where jta is a JTextArea. The output I get is: `<html> <b>Termination time : </b></html> 15`

I have read some forum articles about such a problem, and it was said that `<html><b> </b></html>` would help. But it doesn't.

Please, tell me. where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `JEditorPane` instead of your `JTextArea`.

The following shall work:

```
    JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
    jep.setContentType("text/html");
    jep.setText("<html> <b>Termination time : </b></html>" + CriterionFunction.estimateIndividual_top(individual) + "\n");
```

Comment: Thank you! This work's perfectly. Could you, please, tell me what typeContents may be?